# Display a suggestion list within a ChipBuilder

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working for 7 days on one problem and (even after finding a flutter developer to help) can't find the solution to what should be a very simple option.

I have a Form Field Chip Builder, and I want a list of possible options to be displayed as the user starts typing in to the field.

I have called the list from a Firestore Collection, and can print it out to display in the Console - but I can't get the Chip Builder to pick it up

```
var options1;
  void getOptions() async {
    DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("options")
        .doc("P6E5TbwxN0cofTk8K4ge");
    documentReference.get().then((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.exists) {
        final options1 = datasnapshot.data()['options'];
        print(options1);
        return options1;
      } else {
        print("No such options");
      }
    });
  }
```

The query works, and displays the available options in the Console.

This is the Chip Builder code, it works but it doesn't seem to be able to collect the list from the options1 variable:

```
findSuggestions: (String query) {
 if (query.isNotEmpty) {
  var lowercaseQuery =
   query.toLowerCase();
  return options1.where(
   (options1) => options1
   .toLowerCase()
   .contains(
     query.toLowerCase())
     .toList());
 } else {
  print('empty');
  return const [];
  }
 },
```

If though I don't query the list from the Firestore, and create the options variable as per the below, then the Chip Builder works fine and displays the list of options from this variable:

```
final options1 = [
'Option 1',
'Option 2',
'Option 3'
]
```

Why is the list from the options variable from within the getOptions() function not displaying the options?

Comment: What is your `providers1` variable content ?

Comment: Sorry this was a typo - it should be options1 ..... I have edited this now

Comment: It's a list of strings ?

Comment: The list is an array from a Firestore collection (if that's the right terminology)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
return options1.where((element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(lowercaseQuery));
```

Comment: Is this placed within getOptions or within the Chip Builder findSuggestion option?

Comment: It seems as if 'lowercaseQuery' is undefined?

Comment: But you wrote it yourself here `var lowercaseQuery =  query.toLowerCase();`

Comment: Ahh yes, my apologies. I removed an extra line by mistake when I pasted the code in. OK, the code runs - but unfortunately it is still not providing the suggestions to the Chip Builder though

Comment: I am getting this in the Console - E/flutter (21238): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'where' was called on null.
E/flutter (21238): Receiver: null
E/flutter (21238): Tried calling: where(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic)